# cat vs grep vs awk command get the file content which one is more efficient and less time consuming?

Tags: grep, awk, cat

**Lets say I have file content like this:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming
```

First I have tried:

```
time cat temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Second I have tried:

```
time grep "$"  temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Third I have tried:

```
time awk  "/$/"  temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
```

With:

```
time awk 1 temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

With sed:

```
time sed "" temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a simple file for testing purpose
with few lines in it.
to check the cat and grep command to verfy which is best and less excution time consuming

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

It means cat is quite better command for printing all file content. As it takes less time for execution.?

Comment: Note that `awk 1 temp.txt` should be quicker than `awk '/$/' temp.txt` since it doesn't have to compare each line to a regex.

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that we're on the millisecond scale here. In practical terms, the difference is vanishingly small. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: You might also want to benchmark `sed "" temp.txt`

Comment: `grep` and `awk` and `sed` are for *processing* files.  Obviously processing is going to involve more processing power than *not* processing the file and only outputting its contents as-is.

Comment: @glennjackman Presumably this is a test scenario for a longer task, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but it's worth nothing that the output of `awk` may be different from the other commands because it **adds a newline to its output if the output doesn't end with a newline**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes". Initially, this is more of an assertion, since cat is merely reading the file, whereas the other two are scanning it for an expression. Your `time` scripts are the right idea, but at these extremely low durations, any small variance will give erroneous results. Much better to use a larger file, or to repeat it multiple times.

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do cat temp.txt; done
...
real    0m0.762s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.147s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do grep "$" temp.txt; done
...
real    0m3.128s
user    0m0.667s
sys     0m0.263s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do awk "/$/" temp.txt; done
...
real    0m3.332s
user    0m0.720s
sys     0m0.337s
```

Also (not shown), I ran the above commands multiple times to confirm that each command ran at about the same time, and hence was replicable.

## More benchmarks

As per the comments, here are some more commands I tested. On my system, `grep "^"` and `awk "1"` had no appreciable increase in efficiency, although `sed ""` approached `cat`.

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do grep "^" temp.txt; done
...
real    0m2.992s
user    0m0.527s
sys     0m0.303s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do awk "1" temp.txt; done
...
real    0m3.185s
user    0m0.570s
sys     0m0.317s

$ time for i in {1..1000}; do sed "" temp.txt; done
...
real    0m0.983s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m0.193s
```

Comment: To be noted: even if you do (mis)use `grep` or `awk` for such things, at least use efficient tests. `awk "1"` took about a quarter of the time and `grep "^"` about a third for me. I used `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=100M count=10 | base64 > /tmp/blah` for the file.

Comment: @muru I've added more commands. I was actually quite surprised at how little difference they made (on my system at least).

Answer (score 0):

I have same scripts . In one I'm using cat and in other it's all AWK.

Here's the first one:

```
#!/bin/bash


        lines=$(cat /etc/passwd | wc -l)

        for ((i=1 ; i <=$lines ; i++ ))
        do
        user=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $1}')
        uid=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $3}')
        gid=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $4}')
        shell=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $7}')
        echo -e "User is : $user \t Uid is : $uid \t Gid is : $gid \t Shell is : $shell"
        done
```

Here's the second one:

```
#!/bin/bash


        lines=$(awk  'END {print NR}' /etc/passwd)

        for ((i=1 ; i <=$lines ; i++ ))
        do
        user=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
        uid=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $3}'  /etc/passwd)
        gid=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $4}'  /etc/passwd)
        shell=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $7}' /etc/passwd)
        echo -e "User is : $user \t Uid is : $uid \t Gid is : $gid \t Shell is : $shell"
        done
```

The time taken for the first script  is as follows ( script with CAT statements):

```
real    0m0.215s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.238s
```

For the second script which has only AWK statements, time taken is as follows:

```
real    0m0.132s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.123s
```

I think awk processing of file is much faster as compared to calling other external function for reading the files. I would be happy for a discussion on the results.

i think AWK performs better in some cases.

Comment: This is not comparing like with like.  Here you're running either (a) 'awk', or (b) 'cat' *and* 'awk'.  (b) is slower, which is not much of a surprise since you're running your file through two commands rather than one, but this does *not* demonstrate that 'cat' is slower than 'awk'.